# Is steam a good gas to use for a small RCS thruster on a small rocket?

Tags: rockets, flight-control, rcs

Is steam a reasonable tradeoff from other hot/cryogenic gases in order to have safety and have it easily obtainable?

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is steam from heated water, as opposed to steam from hydrolox or a fuel cell.

Comment: Funny thing is that the literary interpreted ban of the rocket fuels would apply also to this question... "you might burn yourself by the steam", blah-blah.